# who can teach me to install wget to git bash

Tags: wget, git-bash, mingw32

wget.exe
bash: wget.exe: command not found

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$ install wget.exe
install: missing destination file operand after 'wget.exe'
Try 'install --help' for more information.

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$ Git/wget.exe
bash: Git/wget.exe: No such file or directory

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$ pip install wget
bash: pip: command not found

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$ import wget
bash: import: command not found

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$

Comment: Try "apt-get install wget" or "yum install wget"

Answer (score 6):

Download the lastest wget binary for windows from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ (they are available as a zip with documentation, or just an exe)
If you downloaded the zip, extract all (if windows built in zip utility gives an error, use 7-zip).
Rename the file wget64.exe to wget.exe if necessary.
Move wget.exe to your Git\mingw64\bin.

Comment: thank you for attentiion i have download wget.exe from enternallybored.net it located my downloads folder i cannot install it which command i should use to install

Comment: go to the directory where you downloaded the file to run it

Comment: Git\mingw64\bin\

Comment: or Install Cygwin and get the needed application from there. Then you can add Cygwin bin directory into MINGW64 PATH. Something like that:

Comment: MINGW64$export PATH=$PATH:/c/cygwin/bin/

MINGW64$wget --version
GNU Wget 1.18 built on cygwin.

Comment: wget.exe*
 резюме.pdf

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$ Git\mingw64\bin\
> wget.exe
bash: Gitmingw64binwget.exe: command not found

user@admin MINGW32 ~/Downloads
$